# Sync from Android phone's calendar to Google Calendar on web without using Google Calendar Data API. Is this possible?

Tags: android, synchronization, google-calendar-api

From the Google Calendar Help document on the web, it is stated that::

**Is Google Calendar for mobile devices in sync with Google Calendar?**

**Answer:** Yes. Changes made in Google Calendar when accessed from your computer will be reflected in Google Calendar for mobile. For example, if you create a new event in your computer's browser, the event will automatically appear in Google Calendar the next time that you log in from your mobile device.

I have tried this, i created a task in the Google calendar on the web and synced it back to my local default calendar app(as i am connected to the Google account in my mobile, my sync is working fine).But my question is if i create a task in my Local calendar application. Can that appear on the Google Calendar on web. Here i am talking about a sync from Mobile to Web. I dont want to use the Google calendar Data API and achieve it(then it would be a different scenario. I may not even need a default calendar application. I can write a simple application which can push the data onto the Google Calendar on web. Well thats a different story or question...).
The reason i am asking this question is, I found a post related to the Google private Calendar API.

[Working with the Android Calendar](http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm)

Please don't miss the Introduction.
So i suppose it is possible for a reverse sync but i don't know how.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with sync client for Google Calendar supplied by google themselves? (Settings app, select "Accounts & sync" & enable "Auto-sync". Then click your google account entry. You should have an entry for "Sync Calendar").

Comment: The above said process only syncs the tasks from Google Calendar on Web to local calendar on mobile(only after initiating sync). But i want to sync in reverse direction.i.e from Device to Web

Comment: Its a 2-way sync client. It syncs web->client and client->web.

Comment: Hello Jens. Can you please give me some instructions on how to do this client->web sync. I would be very helpful to you.I have tested the web-> client process and sure about it. This 2nd process is what i am not sure about.Thanks

Comment: Try this out <br />
https://support.google.com/calendar/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=13950&p=syncmobile

Comment: Vansi,  I'm using a DroidX. Were your instructions (auto-sync) for settings in the Google Calendar app or the phone settings? (I tried both and the closest I found was Phone>Accounts > sync. But there's not option for autosync there (just "tap to sync now"). It looks like some stuff was sync'd recently, others like Google Play Music, were sync'd 2 months ago.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Early in the morning searched the android forums for this question. Felt very happy to see the following post made by Ryder.

> Sorted it out now, when making an event I had to select my Google account from the top rather than the default my calendar. Works an absolute treat now.

Tested it instantly. Works great. No need of tackling with the Google Calendar API now.

Thanks All

Comment: once an event is created, there isn't a way to change its location. there's also no export function. If like me, you've been creating many events and finally realised they weren't syncing and they've been stored in the catastrophically useless "Default Calendar" there doesn't appear to be a way to migrate them to google. how did no one think of this?

Comment: I think the person who asking the question is expecting an answer like" sync local calendar data and to the Google calendar using an android programme (code).

Answer (score 2):

When you have the calender open and you enter into the settings you will have the email account that you sync back and forth with google on the web and the phone calendar. It never syncs, so just click it until it shows not visible. Then when you go to make a new entry, it will always sync with the email account on the google web and the phone will not be there to confuse you.

Comment: From the calendar app menu, I selected "Calendars to display", and unchecked Phone. Now when I create a new entry, it goes to Google calendar by default (instead of the Phone calendar which is not synced). I believe this is what you meant.