# How can I sync events in calendar after adding event

Tags: android, calendar, synchronization, google-calendar-api

I am adding event like this...

```
public static String EVENT_URI = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
public static String CALENDAR_URI = "content://com.android.calendar/calendars";

public static Uri insert(ContentResolver cr, ContentValues cv) {

    Uri newEvent = null;

    try {
        cv.put(Event.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
        cv.put(Event.TITLE, "title");
        cv.put(Event.DESCRIPTION, "description");
        cv.put(Event.DTSTART, new Date().getTime());
        cv.put(Event.DTEND, new Date().getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60);
        cv.put(Event.EVENT_LOCATION, "Hall: " + "+ 1000 * 60 * 60");
        cv.put(Event.HAS_ALARM, true);
        cv.put(Event.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());

        newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse(EVENT_URI), cv);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newEvent;
}
```

I want to sync with Google calendar after adding event, Is there any parameter which I have to send with `ContentValues` **OR** I need to fire query for `sync`.

how this useful http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#sync-adapter

Help!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sync from Android phone's calendar to Google Calendar on web without using Google Calendar Data API. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834257/sync-from-android-phones-calendar-to-google-calendar-on-web-without-using-googl)

Waiting for best answer because I already given account selection feature.