# Is it possible create google calendar using web API and enable sync for it without any user interaction in mobile app?

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

I can create a calendar using the google web API and it appears in Google Calendar Web app. But to see  the calendar on my android device I need to enable sync for this calendar manually in settings of android version of Google calendar.

Is it possible to enable sync without user interaction?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync) if this is the one that you are looking for and if applicable based on what you need.

This documentation is all about incremental synchronization of calendar data. By using this method, you can keep data for all calendar collections in sync while saving bandwidth.

This incremental synchronization consists of two stages:

1. [Initial full sync](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync#initial_full_sync) is performed once at the very beginning in order to fully synchronize the client’s state with the server’s state. The client will obtain a sync token that it needs to persist.
2. [Incremental sync](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync#incremental_sync) is performed repeatedly and updates the client with all the changes that happened ever since the previous sync. Each time, the client provides the previous sync token, it obtained from the server and stores the new sync token from the response.

For the sample code, just check the code given in the documentation. It also demonstrates how to use sync tokens.

For more information, check these threads:

- [Sync from Android phone's calendar to Google Calendar on web without using Google Calendar Data API. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834257/sync-from-android-phones-calendar-to-google-calendar-on-web-without-using-googl?rq=1)
- [sync event added programmatically with google calendar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918968/sync-event-added-programmatically-with-google-calendar-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: See i don't want to sync anything. I just need to enable sync for specific calendar without asking my user to do this via the android App settings. Maybe I have missed something.